# When "Show window content while dragging " is disabled, dragged window location value does not update in WPF

Tags: wpf, window, mouse, on-location-changed

The reported issue occurs when the check box in below image(This PC -->Properties-->Advanced System Settings-->(under Performance in Advanced tab click Settings)) is disabled.

[image]

Try to get the mouse cursor position while dragging a window in WPF. The location of window is updated only when mouse is pressed and released, not when it window dragged.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private const int WM_MOVING = 0x0216;
    private HwndSource _hwndSrc;
    private HwndSourceHook _hwndSrcHook;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        this.Unloaded += MainWindow_Unloaded;
        
    }

    private void MainWindow_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _hwndSrc.RemoveHook(_hwndSrcHook);
        _hwndSrc.Dispose();
        _hwndSrc = null;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _hwndSrc = HwndSource.FromDependencyObject(this) as HwndSource;
        _hwndSrcHook = FilterMessage;
        _hwndSrc.AddHook(_hwndSrcHook);
    }

    private IntPtr FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        switch (msg)
        {
            case WM_MOVING:
                OnLocationChange();
                break;
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    private void OnLocationChange()
    {
        Rect windowRect = new Rect(this.Left, this.Top, this.Width, this.Height);
    }

}
```

Need the location of window to update when it is dragged by mouse.